# How can I override list methods to do vector addition and subtraction in python?

Tags: python, list, operators, subclass

I originally implemented this as a wrapper class around a list, but I was annoyed by the number of **operator**() methods I needed to provide, so I had a go at simply subclassing list. This is my test code:

```
    class CleverList(list):

        def __add__(self, other):
            copy = self[:]
            for i in range(len(self)):
                copy[i] += other[i]
            return copy

        def __sub__(self, other):
            copy = self[:]
            for i in range(len(self)):
                copy[i] -= other[i]
            return copy

        def __iadd__(self, other):
            for i in range(len(self)):
                self[i] += other[i]
            return self

        def __isub__(self, other):
            for i in range(len(self)):
                self[i] -= other[i]
             return self

    a = CleverList([0, 1])
    b = CleverList([3, 4])
    print('CleverList does vector arith: a, b, a+b, a-b = ', a, b, a+b, a-b)

    c = a[:]
    print('clone test: e = a[:]: a, e = ', a, c)

    c += a
    print('OOPS: augmented addition: c += a: a, c = ', a, c)

    c -= b         
    print('OOPS: augmented subtraction: c -= b: b, c, a = ', b, c, a)
```

Normal addition and subtraction work in the expected manner, but there are problems with the augmented addition and subtraction. Here is the output:

```
    >>> 
    CleverList does vector arith: a, b, a+b, a-b =  [0, 1] [3, 4] [3, 5] [-3, -3]
    clone test: e = a[:]: a, e =  [0, 1] [0, 1]
    OOPS: augmented addition: c += a: a, c =  [0, 1] [0, 1, 0, 1]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/bob/Documents/Python/listTest.py", line 35, in <module>
        c -= b
    TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'list' and 'CleverList'
    >>>
```

Is there a neat and simple way to get augmented operators working in this example?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you not use NumPy arrays for this task? Is this an assignment of some sort, just tinkering? Nothing wrong with it, I'm just curious.

Comment: Hi EMS. Partly I am tinkering, I was looking for something lightweight to write a small app. Numpy seems a bit OTT for what I need, also the vector aspect is only part of what I want.

Comment: Nothing wrong with tinkering; it's a great way to learn and get better.  From a purely practical standpoint though, NumPy is your friend.  Not only does it implement a lot of things that would probably be useful to you, it implements them in C for efficiency, and it's an extremely, extremely common package in Python applications.  The scientific community in particular probably doesn't even know what Python-without-NumPy even is.

Comment: @EMS,John Y: Thanks for your interest. Also, thanks for referring me to numpy. The numpy array looks like the way to go for this sort of thing for practical purposes. Still, I remain curious as to whether there is an elegant solution 'out there' that does not involve external packages. As I mention below, there are two issues, one is the dual nature of the '+' and '+=' operators in this context, the other is how to provide '-' and '-='.

Comment: I think probably whatever NumPy has done is the most 'elegant' solution you'll get. Anything else is at best reinventing the wheel. I can see this as a good exercise for beginning programmers, say in a scientific computing class. Creating one's own complex-valued matrix class with operations defined that behave as expected in all corner cases is a good way to get a feel for any language. But if you want to use this idea to actually do anything, I wouldn't stray from NumPy. As an aside, I also think most idiomatic shortcuts are a bad idea. I try to avoid things like "++" or "+=" in any language

Comment: I understand these things, but I feel that they are silly. If I ever faced a situation where the performance win of += outweighed the clarity/readability win of `x=x+y` then I would use the idiom. In a decade of programming experience, I have *never* encountered such a situation (not even in embedded). But I would never want to fight over it. Programming is a personal thing like writing and if idioms work for others, good for them. I'd rather make a language that interprets `x=x+y` and realizes it should substitute `x+=y` on my behalf, so I get both the direct math clarity *and* performance.

Comment: The idioms should match those that have naturally developed in mathematics. Or at least I prefer those. I would consider it a very bad design if you're in a situation where you want to use += because evaluating x has consequences, and it would be bad design essentially *because* the expression of the idea "increment x by y units" should match naturally with how it's universally done in math, and without any chance of unintended stuff. For tasks outside of scientific computing, there could be idioms that offer expression wins with no loss of clarity, sure, but often this isn't so.

Comment: Assignment is a perfectly natural math concept. Also you are misusing the `=` sign in your example. What you mean is that in math there is no difference between `x == x + y` and `x + y == x`. Just because in programming one often uses a slightly different *alphabet* (where `=` means assignment and `==` means "is equal to") doesn't mean that the programmatic way of expressing it violates the math way. Assignment is a math concept too, and it's fine to use `=` to represent it.

Comment: The problem occurs when you start obfuscating the math; when you use programmatic shorthands that obscure the operations and their order. In general this is why I like functional programming a great deal, and why I favor Python for imperative and scientific computing. It should be all about clarity and expressiveness for the programmer; all about expressing math operations on data as naturally as you can. Shortcuts are fine, but everyone's going to want her or his own specific shortcuts, so why not give them the power to do that, and not force them to adopt the preferences of a few others?

Comment: @EMS: Our conversation about idioms is pretty much irrelevant to this question, so I'm removing my previous comments about it (and leaving this one in case others stumbling upon this later are confused). I could easily continue the conversation, but here is not the best place.

Answer (score 5):

You did not override the [`__getslice__` method](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getslice__), so your `c` is a `list`:

```
>>> a = CleverList([0, 1])
>>> a
[0, 1]
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.CleverList'>
>>> type(a[:])
<type 'list'>
```

Here is a off-the-cuff version:

```
def __getslice__(self, *args, **kw):
    return self.__class__(super(CleverList, self).__getslice__(*args, **kw))
```

Comment: The link you provided says this is deprecated. I believe you should be using [`__getitem__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__).

Comment: @EMS: builtin types still implement it and for list you need to override it.

Comment: `self.__class__` is just a fancy way to say `type(self)`. BTW, Python misses something to easily access class methods and members (like the `@@something` from Ruby...)

Comment: Thx to all contributors above. This is a partial answer, in that override of the slicing is required. However, this creates new errors elsewhere. The nub of the issue is there are two __add__ (and __iadd__) methods, and they are both needed to make it work. The parent list method is needed by the slicing. The override is needed for the math. There are different issues with -=, because list does not have this operator and rejects it.